# Java library for RMI on peers in a peer to peer network

Tags: java, rmi, p2p

I am looking for a p2p library for java which enables me to do a RMI on a peer node without sending other data over network than the method parameters.

Required Features:

- peer-to-peer with automatic group discovery and joining
- automatic replication of shared objects (in case of a peer leaves the group)
- discover the nearest peer and execute a method on a shared object on this peer (which means not sending the object to the requestor)
- under current maintenance

What I have found so far is TomP2P - where I am not sure if I can execute methods on peers or just share (copying) data. And JXTA which seems some kind of "out of development" (the latest commit was 4 years ago).

I know questions about libraries are always difficult due to personal preference or to be too broad. So just giving me some starting points will be absolutely ok.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Jini, but peer-to-peer RMI is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP I mean remote method invocation on shared objects in a p2p group as a concept not as a protocoll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found JGroups which is not exactly a P-2-P solution but I can bend it to my needs. The have a well working RPC api which I could simply wrap around the java proxy object and it behaves very much like RMI.